# .toggleClass('active') not removing active when other link is clicked

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am trying to do a pretty straight-forward slideToggle, as well as toggleClass ('active'). It currently works on itself (toggling active), but it's not removing active when I click on a different link. I know I am missing something fairly simple, and wondering what it is. Any suggestions?

```js
        $('.content').hide();
        $('.expander').click(function(x) {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
            var toggle = $(this).nextUntil('.expander');
            toggle.slideToggle();
        $('.content').not(toggle).slideUp();
        x.preventDefault();
        });
```

```css
.expander {background: red; width: 100%; padding: 10px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; text-decoration: none;}
.expander.active {background: black;}
.content {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <a class="expander" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <div class="content">
        <ul class="list">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    <a class="expander" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <div class="content">
        <ul class="list">
          <li>6</li>
          <li>7</li>
          <li>8</li>
          <li>9</li>
          <li>10</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    <a class="expander" href="#">Link 3</a>
      <div class="content">
        <ul class="list">
          <li>11</li>
          <li>12</li>
          <li>13</li>
          <li>14</li>
          <li>15</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need remove class `active` from all elements with class `expander` before you toggle. Also, to toggle on an active element, check if it has a class `active` associated with it.

```
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.expander').click(function(x) {
    var toggleClass = $(this).hasClass('active') ? true : false;
    $('.expander').removeClass('active');    
    if(!toggleClass)
      $(this).toggleClass('active');         
    var toggle = $(this).nextUntil('.expander');
    toggle.slideToggle();
    $('.content').not(toggle).slideUp();
    x.preventDefault();
    });
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/98vbmryj/2/

Comment: works perfect...thank you. I knew I was just missing something simple :)

Comment: A vote up is better than a Thank You. And please mark this answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner.

```
$('.expander').click(function(x) {
    $(this).addClass('active').next('.content').slideDown().prev('.expander').siblings('.expander').removeClass('active').next('.content').slideUp();
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
//$('.content').hide();
$('.expander').click(function(x) {
 $(this).addClass('active').next('.content').slideDown().prev('.expander').siblings('.expander').removeClass('active').next('.content').slideUp();
});
```

```css
.expander {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.expander.active {
  background: black;
}
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="expander" href="#">Link 1</a>
<div class="content">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<a class="expander" href="#">Link 2</a>
<div class="content">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<a class="expander" href="#">Link 3</a>
<div class="content">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```